# Call stored procedure fail due to Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this current SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetHighestDrop]
  @val1 AS FLOAT ,
  @val2 AS FLOAT ,
  @val3 AS FLOAT 
AS
BEGIN
select case when @val1 < @val2 then
               case when @val1 < @val3 then @val1
               else @val3
               end
        when @val2 < @val3 then @val2
               else @val3
    end
END
```

I am calling it with this syntax:

```
SELECT
GetHighestDrop @val1=((clmnA/clmnB)-1)*100,@val2=2,@val3=3
FROM dbo.tstTable
```

clmnA and clmbB contain numbers, if I run them seperately, like:

```
SELECT ((clmnA/clmnB)-1)*100 FROM dbo.tstTable
```

I get a result, which is a float, but when I run it through GetHighestDrop, it fails.

Any idea why?

Comment: Instead of a stored procedure you should create a _function_ for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call a stored procedure with `exec`.  There is no way to run a stored procedure inside a `select`.

Consider converting your procedure to a [scalar user-defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

Example function use (don't forget the schema name, usually "dbo"):

```
select  dbo.GetHighestDrop( ((clmnA/clmnB)-1)*100, 2, 3) as Col1
from    dbo.tstTable
```

Comment: I have added a function, but it still doesnt work, what would be the syntax?

Comment: Added an example query that calls a scalar function

Answer (score 0):

could it be that your stored procedure do not return any value? try out functions which has to return at least one value. if you want to use stored procedures, then you have to add an `out` parameter.